# Transition of background-color without being triggered

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a background color transition, where element A's color will switch to another color on hover. But A's color is already switched without hovering on it.

```
.A
    {
        background-color: #1A1A1F;
    }
.A:hover
    {
        background-color: #424242;
        transition:  background-color,0.5s ;
        -o-transition: background-color, 0.5s ;
        -moz-transition:  background-color, 0.5s;
        -webkit-transition:  background-color, 0.5s;
         cursor: pointer;
    }
```

Here A's color should be #1A1A1F by default and switch to #424242 when you hover on it, but instead of being the default color, it's already changed without hovering on it.

Comment: `.A` is a class, `A` is the anchor element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should put the transition in the main selector in `:hover` selector, puting the transition in `:hover` will give you a different result.
Second, the transition should be defined like : `transition: background-color 0.5s;`, no comma in between. You should put the comma when you have different transitions like : `transition: background-color .5s, width 1s;`.
If you have multiple transitions and you want to give them the same transition duration you can use `all` or not give a property name like `transition: all 1s;` or `transition: 1s;`.
Anyways, your code should be like this:

```
.A{
    background-color:#1A1A1F;
    transition: background-color .5s;
}
.A:hover{
    background-color:#424242;
}
```